# In the context of SQL server agent, what is a job server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

When you script a SQL agent job, there will be a sp_add_jobserver invocation in the script. I checked the documentation about this stored procedure but still can't understand what is a job server. As I understand, when you create a job, you are always create it on a specific server. Later you can run the job on that server. So why we need to use this stored procedure to combine a job to a server?

Comment: “when you create a job, you are always create it on a specific server. Later you can run the job on that server”,actually,it's not.When you create a job without sp_add_jobserver,the job will be in the job list of the target server,but it could not be executed successly.An error will ocurred: "Cannot start the job "XXX" (ID xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx) because it does not have any job server or servers defined. Associate the job with a job server by calling sp_add_jobserver."

Comment: @wangguanguo so if I deploy a job on server a and use sp_add_jobserver to combine the job with server a, I can successfully run the job on server a. But what if I combine the job with another server b? In that case the job is on a (there is no job definition on b) and I combined it with b on server a. If I start the job in this case, what will happen?

Comment: a job cannot both on a and b.If you sp_add_jobserver a job to  b you will get an error: This job is currently targeted at a remote server so cannot also be targeted at the local server.You must delete the job in "a" first. After doing this ,the job is in the list of [SQL Server Agnet]-[Jobs]-[Multi-Server Jobs] in SSMS.You can execute it,and it will affect the server b.

Answer (score 3):

To explan more details in here:
To add a job to a different server,you must make a server the master server,and add target server(s) to it.After doing this,the SQL Server Agent in SSMS will become this:

[image: SQL Server Agent MSX]

The DelPDFHis job is target on another server:
[image: Job Properties of targets page]

And the target server will download it to local.
[image: Target server Status]

[image]

When executing the job in server a,it will execute in server b too.